# Django queued storages [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, linux, django, ubuntu, django-storage

So i know there are similar questions but they haven't helped me solving my problem.

I am trying out `django-queued-storage` and although my file uploads worked fine before, now that i added it am getting a `[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/curriculum.pdf'`

i tried setting permissions to my media file like this: `sudo chmod 777 -R media/` (i know its BAD) and a bunch of other permission tips but without any luck.

Any idea how i can fix this? Im using a vagrant machine with ubuntu 14.04

these are my folder permissions

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/media$ ls -latr
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 4096 Jul 15 11:52 .
drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 4096 Jul 15 12:04
```

this is my settings :

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'

STATIC_URL = S3_URL + STATIC_ROOT
MEDIA_URL = S3_URL + MEDIA_ROOT
```

and my model:

```
queued_s3storage = QueuedStorage(
    'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage',
    'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
)

fulltext_pdf_file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=False, upload_to='.', storage=queued_s3storage)
```

Comment: your ls command shows /vagrant/media, not /media. You probably want to do a chmod on /media instead of just media (which is probably /vagrant/media).

Comment: @rje `vagrant` is the root folder for my project. for example if i do `ls -l` in it i see `drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  4096 Jul 15 11:52 media` which is the folder where i upload my media files to. and i did `sudo chmod 777 -R media/` inside my vagrant folder a.k.a project root folder

Comment: But the error says "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/curriculum.pdf'" which is referring to the absolute path /media. So apparently that's where Django tries to save the file. Maybe you should remove the slash in front of MEDIA_ROOT?

Comment: thanks @rje you pointed me in the right direction. my problem was the `MEDIA_URL`

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @rje i found the problem. so the problem was actually in the configurations were i was trying to write to the wrong folder.
so the fix was:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'
MEDIA_URL = S3_URL + '/' + MEDIA_ROOT
```